# How to get all tweets for a specified user using C#

Tags: c#, twitter, console-application, tweetsharp

I have the following code written in C# which gets tweets for a specified user. The problem I am facing is that it returns only 15-20 tweets of a person who has over 7000 tweets. In some cases it also gives this error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.OverflowException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Additional information: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
```

My code:

```
        var service = new TwitterService(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
        service.AuthenticateWith(accessToken, accessTokenSecret);

        var options = new SearchOptions { Q = "abcd" };
        var tweets = service.Search(options);
        var count = 0;
        foreach (var tweet in tweets.Statuses)
            count++;

        Console.WriteLine(count);
```

Error occurs in the line `var tweets = service.Search(options);`

I am using TweetSharp library

Comment: really ? a for each to do a count of a collection. You just made my morning :). If there is a search option to limit that amount returned try setting to let say 10 then increase. The error says you are hitting some kind of limit.

Comment: I was printing the tweets initially...hence the foreach...but after that inorder for some debugging i used the count...

Comment: There is no option to set the search limit.

Answer (score 2):

I am the developer of [Tweetinvi](https://tweetinvi.codeplex.com). I just wanted to let you know that it is quite easy to do what you get all tweets from a Twitter user.

What you need to understand is that you can only get a maximum 200 tweets from the REST API with a single query.

Therefore you will need to iterate over the list of results as followed.

```
    private static ITweet[] GetUserTimelineTweets(string userName, int maxNumberOfTweets)
    {
        var tweets = new List<ITweet>();

        var receivedTweets = Timeline.GetUserTimeline(userName, 200).ToArray();
        tweets.AddRange(receivedTweets);

        while (tweets.Count < maxNumberOfTweets && receivedTweets.Length == 200)
        {
            var oldestTweet = tweets.Min(x => x.Id);
            var userTimelineParameter = Timeline.CreateUserTimelineRequestParameter(userName);
            userTimelineParameter.MaxId = oldestTweet;
            userTimelineParameter.MaximumNumberOfTweetsToRetrieve = 200;

            receivedTweets = Timeline.GetUserTimeline(userTimelineParameter).ToArray();
            tweets.AddRange(receivedTweets);
        }

        return tweets.Distinct().ToArray();
    }
```

Cheers,
Linvi

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply...Is this library available/compatible with windows phone 8.1? Also, if a user has around 500 tweets, then will executing the query thrice get me the tweets?

Comment: Tweetinvi is compatible with Windows Phone 8 and 8.1 and yes the query will be executed 3 times.